# Selenium page object model python, inherit from particular class

Tags: python, selenium, object, pom.xml, models

Trying to implement page object model practise with selenium and python but an instance of chrome is not launching. can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm expecting Chrome to launch and fill in a login form.

this is what the console is spitting out currently: Process finished with exit code 0. And an " unresolved reference 'Login' " error on the Login_test method.

Also getting a red line under Login. while trying to use it in the test_login method.

This is how my files are set up. I have 2 python files in separate folders. Both of these folders are in a project folder.

Pages/login_page.py

Tests/login_test.py

```
#login_page.py file
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Login:
    _username_input = {"by": By.NAME, "value": "username"}
    _password_input = {"by": By.NAME, "value": "password"}
    _submit_button = {"by": By.ID, "value": "btn-inloggen"}
    _success_message = {"by": By.CSS_SELECTOR, "value": ".#header > div.right > a:nth-child(4)"}

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.driver.get("website")

    def with_(self, username, password):
        self.driver.find_element(self._username_input["by"],
                                 self._username_input["value"]).send_keys(username)
        self.driver.find_element(self._password_input["by"],
                                 self._password_input["value"]).send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element(self._submit_button["by"],
                                 self._submit_button["value"]).click()

    def login_succesfull_(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(self._success_message["by"],
                                        self._success_message["value"]).is_displayed()<

#test_login.py file
from selenium import webdriver
from Pages import login_page

class TestLogin:

    def login(self, request):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()

        def quit():
            driver.quit()
        request.addfinalizer(quit)
        return login_page.Login(driver)

    def test_login(self):
        Login.with_("username", "password")
        assert Login.login_succesfull_()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can help you if you ask a specific question and provide more detail. What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: Chrome needs to launch and fill in a login form. Currently the console is spitting out: Process finished with exit code 0. 

Also there's a red line under Login. class while using it in the test_login function.

Comment: Hover your mouse over `Login`. What error does it say?

Comment: unresolved reference 'Login'

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: What testing framework are you using? For example, are you using unittest or pytest or something else?

Comment: Pytest is the idea.

Comment: Please answer both of my questions. "Page object model" is a guideline for organizing your code in a test. You still need to choose a testing framework as well. How do you run your code? Are you using PyCharm or some other IDE?

Comment: in this method

def test_login(self):
        Login.with_("username", "password")
        assert Login.login_succesfull_()

Comment: Also im using pycharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because there is no name `Login` defined in the available scopes where you are using it. Instead you must use the qualified name `login_page.Login` as in your `login()` function.

However, more importantly, you cannot call `with_()` or `login_succesfull_()` on the class name. Instead, you need an instance of the `Login` class.

There are several pieces missing that are needed to fix this. First of all, Selenium is often used within the context of a testing framework. This isn't strictly required but is the most common use case. PyCharm defaults to running tests with unittest. To use unittest, you must create a class which inherits from the `TestCase` class:

```
import unittest.TestCase

class TestLogin(TestCase):
    pass
```

Most such classes will have a `setUp()` method which initializes the fixture for each test in the class. For example, this is where you can perform the login:

```
import unittest.TestCase

class TestLogin(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.page = self.login()
```

Next, your `login()` function takes a `request` parameter which it never uses. You can just remove it:

```
def login(self):
    ...
```

Now in your test, use the `page` member variable which we created in `setUp()`:

```
def test_login(self):
    self.page.with_("username", "password")
    assert self.page.login_succesfull_()
```

I suggest that you read more about `unittest` before continuing with Selenium. You also need to learn more about Object Oriented Programming in Python, especially the syntax required to create and use objects.

Comment: just spent an hour reading up on unittest framework. and applied your feedback to my script. It worked . thanks so much.